# Checking triangle inequality in a massive numpy matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, distance

I have a symmetric NumPy matrix `D` of non-negative floating point numbers. A number in the `i`th row and `j`th column represents the distance between objects `i` and `j`, whatever they are. The matrix is large (~10,000 rows/columns). I would like to check if all the distances in the matrix obey the triangle inequality, that is: `D[i,j]<=D[i,k]+D[k,j]` for all `i`, `j`, `k`.

The problem can be solved, quite inefficiently, by using a triple-nested loop. But is there a faster, vectorized solution?

Comment: Trying to fully vectorize the triple loop would probably cost way too much memory and not be worth it. Vectorizing one or two inner loops would probably be worthwhile. I wonder whether there's an algorithmic improvement.

Comment: Since it contains 10k rows/columns, doing a check will result in at least 1000G checks (this is the "intrensic" complexity), so yes vectorizing will boost this significantly, but it will still take a lot of time.

Comment: Barring algorithmic improvements, the simplest answer is probably to just throw Numba at the problem, and maybe experiment with loop ordering or cache blocking if you need more improvement.

Comment: [This question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16827/algorithm-to-check-whether-a-complete-undirected-graph-is-fullfilling-the-trian) on the CS site suggests that matrix multiplication could be used somehow, but offers no details on how to do that.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you for pointing to the CS site. However, their proposed solution is more theoretical than practical. I would be more interested in knowing if there is an intrinsic NumPy way of running the triple-nested loop without resorting to the Python `for` loops.

Comment: @user2357112: the idea of squaring the matrix is that you obtain the "weight" of all possible two hops. But there is a "catch": here it means that we sum over all possible ways to hope from *A* to *C* so not through *one* node, but through *all* nodes. It sums up these paths, and multiplies the edges. With a *log* transformation, we can change the multiplicative behavior, but the "through all" is harder.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Yeah, I got that far. I don't see any way to reach the goal, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly vectorise the innermost loop easily enough with (untested):

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i):
        assert all(D[i,j] <= D[i,:] + D[:,j])
```

For double vectorisation you can loop through `k` (also untested):

```
for k in range(N):
    row = D[k,:].reshape(1, N)
    col = D[:,k].reshape(N, 1)
    assert (D <= row + col).all()
```

(`row + col` generates a square matrix the same size as `D`)